# absolute URI to font in resource

Tags: wpf, fonts, resources, uri, absolute

I would like use custom font in my WPF app.

I created folder fonts in my project and added .ttf file. Then I setup build action for .ttf file to resource.

When I access to font in XAML via absolute URI it doesnt’t work.

```
            <TextBlock Margin = "5"
                       FontSize = "50"
                       FontFamily="pack://application:,,,/fonts/Sketch College.ttf">
                Custom font
            </TextBlock>
```

Where is problem?

Because if I use relative URI it works.

```
            <TextBlock Margin = "5"
                       FontSize = "40"
                       FontFamily = "./fonts/#Sketch College">
                Custom fonts
            </TextBlock>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

WPF applications do not allow you to create a FontFamily object programmatically using "pack:" as part of the absolute uniform resource identifier (URI) reference to a font. For example, "pack://application:,,,/resources/#Pericles Light" is an invalid font reference.
Got it from
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms753303(v=vs.110).aspx